# Google cloud sql access denied exception in local

Tags: java, hibernate, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I've pasted the full stack trace here - 
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/nG8shz7j).

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission localhost resolve)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at 

    com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:283)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1031)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1145)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1083)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1019)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:243)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:284)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2043)
        ... 123 more
    Caused by:

    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Here is my database properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tester
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

And applicationCOntext -

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
      <value>/WEB-INF/classes/database.properties</value>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref local="dataSource"/>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">
          false
        </prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">
          false
        </prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
```

Here is how I tried to use it -

```
public class MainDao {
  protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }

  public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }

  private Session openSession(){
    return this.sessionFactory.openSession();
  }
}
```

I get the error when I call openSession. Need help with this. I'm not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: I think you need to use Eclipselink rather than Hibernate. I tried using Hibernate and got the same error. I solved the problem by switching to Eclipselink. Read the examples and they use eclipselink.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing database properties to these

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:google:rdbms://localhost/database
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

And then running the `dev_appserver.cmd` command with following jvm args -

```
-Drdbms.server=local
-Drdbms.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
-Drdbms.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdatabase?user=username&password=password
```

This worked for me. The command on the command prompt was not working(showing error) but in my IDE(intellij idea) after specifying above as jvm parameters it worked.